# Grouping values into equal range bins

Tags: python

Say I have a set of values `[1, 4, 8, 9, 12, 15]`

I'm looking to have these grouped by bins of equal ranges,
eg. `1-5, 6-10, 11-15, 16-20, ...`

Using the set of values above, the output would fit into the bins as such:
`[1, 4], [8, 9], [12, 15]`

Is there a pythonic way of going about this?

Comment: Look at using integer division. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I would suggest adding your edit as an answer and accepting it if that solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

you could use list comprehension :

```py
r = 5
l = [1, 4, 8, 9, 12, 15]
bins = [1 + i*r for i in range(max(l)//r + 1)]
bins_list = [[x for x in l if bins[i]<= x < bins[i+1]] for i in range(len(bins)-1)]
print(bins_list) 
# [[1, 4], [8, 9], [12, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Was under the impression that the `groupby` function only accepted keys with boolean outputs eg. `lambda l : l % 2 == 0`

I've modified it as such:

```
def create_grouping(threshold: int):
    return itertools.groupby(values, lambda l: l // threshold)
```

This gives back a list of groupings.